# Everything randomly freezes in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS while using GUI

Tags: dual-boot, updates, uefi, freeze

After the installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, when I try to update though the software updater, my computer just gets slower (I can tell by the movement of the mouse) and then, everything simply freezes: Keyboard, mouse, I can't even summon the terminal.

I seem to be able to update the software from the linux shell (ctrl+alt+F1) through

> sudo apt-get update

and

> sudo apt-get upgrade

Apparently, my PC also freezes when I try to install software through the terminal. It is possible that Unity Desktop causes this, or, perhaps it is the graphical drivers (this is only speculation).

[This is the part of the installation in which Ubuntu froze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGYRq.jpg)

[This is the shell successfully installing the same software I previously tried to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDsb7.jpg)

I've already tried to redownload ubuntu, reinstalling it (using both Bootable flash drive and a DVD), but none of that seems to work.

-Other details-

I'm not sure about which other information I can provide, so here are the specs of my laptop:

I'm dual-booting with Windows 10

Windows: Windows 10 Home Single Language (64 bit)

Processor: AMD A9-9410 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G 2.90GHz

RAM: 8,00gGB

The model of the laptop is Asus X555QG-XO099T

could it be UEFI/drivers related?

Comment: This question is extremely broad, and you are asking a lot of questions, and not providing much information about what happens. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/967747/edit) your question and add more detail about the errors you are experiencing

Comment: What specifically is keeping you from installing any of other Linux distro?

Comment: I'd rather have an Ubuntu-similar distro, I'm not an expert user and I really need the GUI for most of my projects. I've read that apparently this issue might related with my drivers, unfortunately, it seems AMD doesn't give any more support for my GPU for Linux. I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was Driver-related, since there is not support for these processor and GPU drivers for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

The solution was downgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (where there are available drivers), now I'm dealing with connection problems but those are unrelated.

The real question would be: 
Can I upgrade back to 16.04 LTS without breaking everything again?